# Instantiating a class with a generic type parameter in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to write a factory class to return an instance of a class with a generic parameter type. I think this can be done using reflection but I am confused as to how.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
 public class GenericObjectFactory {

 public GenericObject<?> getGenericObject(Class clazz){
 // I want to return a new instance here of the generic object with type parameter clazz. So something like this...
 return new GenericObject<clazz>();
```

}

anyone any idea how it's done?

I know I can instantiate clazz with newInstance but I want GenericObject. 
     ie getGenericObject (string.getClass()) would return a new GenericObject < String >();

Sorry this post is a bit rambly. I hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Tracey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical clear solution for your problem is the following:

```
public class GenericObjectFactory {
    public <T> GenericObject<T> getGenericObject(Class<T> clazz){
        return new GenericObject<T>();
    }
}
```

Since `T` is erasure, so the new created instance of `GenericObject` even does not "know" what is the value of its parameter `T`, you will probably want to pass the `clazz` to constructor of `GenericObject`

```
public class GenericObjectFactory {
    public <T> GenericObject<T> getGenericObject(Class<T> clazz){
        return new GenericObject<T>(clazz);
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to define such constructor.

EDIT

Here is the usage example:

```
GenericObjectFactory factory = new GenericObjectFactory();
GenericObject<String> gs = factory.getGenericObject(String.class);
GenericObject<Integer> gs = factory.getGenericObject(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Will this not leave me with the same problem? Only now I need to instantiate the class in the constructor rather than the factory?

Comment: The problem in your code is that it cannot be compiled because it is syntactically wrong. Both my snippets are compiled without warnings and work, so the same problem does not exist here.

Comment: I understand that my code is wrong. I was just using is as an example to explain what I was trying to do. If it were correct I would not have to ask the question... In the constructor though, even with your example I am unsure of how to instantiate the class with a specific type that is passed in at run time.

Comment: No, this doesn't help. Because I will not be able to do: GenericObject<String> gs = factory.getGenericObject(String.class);

Comment: Why? This is exactly what I have written in my example.

Comment: In your example you know it is a string/integer object you are creating at compile time. I won't have this information until runtime unfortunately.

Comment: essentially what I am asking is, what would your constructor look like in this example?

Comment: Like, would something like     public T GenericObject (T t)
    {
       this.t = t;
    } be the correct way to construst the genric object on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following:

```
public <T> GenericObject<T> getGenericObject(){
    return new GenericObject<T>();
}
```

---

Example usage:

```
GenericObject<String> obj = genericObjectFactory.getGenericObject();
```

Comment: but how does it know what T is? I'm explicityly passing T in. I want T to be clazz in the above example.

Comment: You don't need to do it explicitely. It will determine the type by looking at the variable (obj in my example)

Comment: The problem with this is my use case. Though maybe there is a better way to do this. So I am trying to wire a bean with spring and I wanted to get back a generic bean based on the type I pass in. So something like:   
 <bean id="myGenericBean" class="com.foo.GenericObjectFactory" factory-method = "getGenericObject">  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="java.lang.String"/></bean>